# How to make a call on my iPhone with speaker mode in code

Tags: ios, swift

Is there an audioManager class in iOS as in Android so that I can set my phone call in speaker mode automatically?

```
audioManager = AudioManager()
audioManager.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL)
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true)
```

Comment: As far as I know, there are no OS level classes that allow you to change global settings, your app is sandboxed in iOS and you only have access to your own application and some other areas provided by the iOS SDK's

Answer (score 0):

You can change the output route of the current audio temporarily using the following method

```
do {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord) 
    //Set the category as per your requirement

    try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker) 
    // or AVAudioSessionPortOverride.none to disable the speaker
}
catch let error{
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Try without setting any category. If you are already in a call, it has already set a category for you. Then overriding the audioport would affect that call

Comment: I try the following code, but failed:
    try audioSession.setCategory(.ambient, mode: .default, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
    and try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
but got this error message: (Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 )

Comment: second attempt:  
     UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do{
            try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
        }
        catch let error{
            print( error )
        }
     still failed

Comment: Figure what else is using the AVAudioSession in your app? if you are trying for a single audio file, you can try with a sample code you can find anywhere. Google the error that prints. Also, make sure the phone is not on silent mode, the ringer is on, and the volume is not low etc.